# How to keep decimals out of text box inputs in VB

Tags: vb.net

I'm new to VB and I am trying to make a calculator to calculate the number of tickets sold.  I need to make it where I can't put a decimal in dblAdultTicketsSold and dblChildTicketsSold. I have restrictions on now that wont allow negative numbers and will only allow numerics.  I appreciate any help.

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click

```
    ''Declare local variables
    Dim decAdultPricePerTicket As Decimal
    Dim dblAdultTicketsSold As Double
    Dim decGrossAdultSalesTotal As Decimal
    Dim decChildPricePerTicket As Decimal
    Dim dblChildTicketsSold As Double
    Dim decGrossChildSalesTotal As Decimal
    Dim decGrossSalesTotal As Decimal
    Dim decNetAdultSalesTotal As Decimal
    Dim decNetChildSalesTotal As Decimal
    Dim decNetTotalSales As Decimal




    'Put backcolor back to white after it turns yellow
    txtAdultPricePerTicket.BackColor = Color.White
    txtAdultTicketsSold.BackColor = Color.White
    txtChildPricePerTicket.BackColor = Color.White
    txtChildTicketsSold.BackColor = Color.White


    ' Validate Inputs

    Try

        'Validate Adult Price Per Ticket is positive numeric
        If IsNumeric(txtAdultPricePerTicket.Text) Then
            decAdultPricePerTicket = CDec(txtAdultPricePerTicket.Text)
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a positive numeric value for Price per Adult Ticket.")
            txtAdultPricePerTicket.Focus()
            txtAdultPricePerTicket.BackColor = Color.Yellow
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If decAdultPricePerTicket < 1 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a positive numeric value for Price per Adult Ticket.")
            txtAdultPricePerTicket.Focus()
            txtAdultPricePerTicket.BackColor = Color.Yellow
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'Validate amount of Adult tickets with positive numeric
        If IsNumeric(txtAdultTicketsSold.Text) Then
            dblAdultTicketsSold = CDbl(txtAdultTicketsSold.Text)
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a positive numeric value for amount for Adult Tickets Sold.")
            txtAdultTicketsSold.Focus()
            txtAdultTicketsSold.BackColor = Color.Yellow
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If dblAdultTicketsSold < 1 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a positive numeric value for amount for Adult Tickets Sold.")
            txtAdultTicketsSold.Focus()
            txtAdultTicketsSold.BackColor = Color.Yellow
            Exit Sub
        End If


        'Validate Child Price per Tickets is a positive numeric

        If IsNumeric(txtChildPricePerTicket.Text) Then
            decChildPricePerTicket = CDec(txtChildPricePerTicket.Text)
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a positive numeric value for Price per Child Ticket.")
            txtChildPricePerTicket.Focus()
            txtChildPricePerTicket.BackColor = Color.Yellow
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If decChildPricePerTicket < 1 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a positive numeric value for Price per Child Ticket.")
            txtChildPricePerTicket.Focus()
            txtChildPricePerTicket.BackColor = Color.Yellow
            Exit Sub
        End If


        'Validate amount of child tickets with positive numeric

        If IsNumeric(txtChildTicketsSold.Text) Then
            dblChildTicketsSold = CDbl(txtChildTicketsSold.Text)
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a positive numeric value for amount of  Child Tickets.")
            txtChildTicketsSold.Focus()
            txtChildTicketsSold.BackColor = Color.Yellow
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If dblChildTicketsSold < 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a positive numeric value for amount of Child Tickets.")
            txtChildTicketsSold.Focus()
            txtChildTicketsSold.BackColor = Color.Yellow
            Exit Sub
        End If






        'Calculate and display GrossAdultSalesTotal

        decGrossAdultSalesTotal = CDec(CDec(txtAdultPricePerTicket.Text) * CDbl(txtAdultTicketsSold.Text))
        lblGrossAdultSalesTotal.Text = decGrossAdultSalesTotal.ToString("c")

        'Calculate and display GrossChildSalesTotal
        decGrossChildSalesTotal = CDec(CDec(txtChildPricePerTicket.Text) * CDbl(txtChildTicketsSold.Text))
        lblGrossChildSalesTotal.Text = decGrossChildSalesTotal.ToString("c")

        'Calculate total gross sales
        decGrossSalesTotal = decGrossAdultSalesTotal + decGrossChildSalesTotal
        lblGrossTotalSales.Text = decGrossSalesTotal.ToString("c")

        'Calculate Net adult ticket sales 20%
        decNetAdultSalesTotal = CDec(0.2 * decGrossAdultSalesTotal)
        lblNetAdultSalesTotal.Text = decNetAdultSalesTotal.ToString("c")

        'Calculate Net child ticket sales 20%
        decNetChildSalesTotal = CDec(0.2 * decGrossChildSalesTotal)
        lblNetChildSalesTotal.Text = decNetChildSalesTotal.ToString("c")

        'Calculate Net total of adult and child tickets
        decNetTotalSales = decNetChildSalesTotal + decNetAdultSalesTotal
        lblNetTotalSales.Text = decNetTotalSales.ToString("c")

    Catch
        'Error Message
        MessageBox.Show("All inputs must be valid positive numeric values")
    End Try


End Sub
```

Comment: Is this a Winforms app or ?

Comment: Might be easier to use a NumericUpDown

Comment: I guess, you have already done the validations. Does it work?

Comment: If you can't have decimal, make them integers...

Comment: With the code I provided everything works.  I just needed a way to not allow decimals in the ticket amount text boxes. I have a ticket amount text box for each Adult and Child ticket amounts.  You can't have 1.5 tickets so I need the user to not be allowed to put in decimals in those two text boxes.

Comment: I tried making them integers but that doesn't keep the user from entering decimals into the text box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a NumericUpDown you can add all these rules to the control...it already disallows alpha characters by default, and if the minimum is set to zero and increment set to 1, then it will disallow negative and decimal numbers. If you decide to stick with your textbox, I always prefer to limit the user's input as they're entering it rather than blow up their screen with error messages when they click the "submit" button or whatever, and you can mimic the NumericUpDown's text filters like so:

```
'Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    TextBox1.Text = Regex.Replace(TextBox1.Text, "[^0-9]", "")
    TextBox1.Select(TextBox1.Text.Length, 0)
End Sub
```

---

Edit: If you need the user to be alerted when they try to enter a decimal number, then you could try this:

```
Private Sub txtAdultPricePerTicket_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtAdultPricePerTicket.TextChanged
    If txtAdultPricePerTicket.Text.Contains(".") Then
        MessageBox.Show("You can't buy a piece of a ticket dummy") '(may want to replace message text)
        txtAdultPricePerTicket.BackColor = Color.Yellow
        txtAdultPricePerTicket.Focus()
        txtAdultPricePerTicket.Select(txtAdultPricePerTicket.Text.IndexOf("."), 1)
    End If
End Sub
```

It will display an error message and highlight the decimal so they can change it

Comment: I tried this and what it did was force for example 1.5 to be 15.  I need it to not let you put in bad data.  I need it to alert the user to input a valid number so that they double check the value being inputted.  I appreciate the suggestion and it did work, I should have explained in more detail what I needed.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood...I've added an edit that might work for you

Comment: That worked great.  Thanks for the help.  I never would have thought to approach it in a manner as simply not allowing that character in the input.  I thought you would have some special control that would take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

This will override the `.` character when pressed using the keyboard.

```
 Private Sub tbKeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles dblAdultTicketsSold.KeyPress, dblChildTicketsSold.KeyPress
       If e.KeyChar = "." Then
            e.Handled = True
       End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to insert this into my code to try it.  When I put in code it showed red lines under e.KeyChar and e.Handled. Thanks